# How to add custom shortcuts in tinyMCE 3.5

Tags: tinymce, keyboard-shortcuts, tinymce-3

"Ctrl + A = Select All

Ctrl + C = Copy

Ctrl + V = Paste

Ctrl + Z = Undo

Ctrl+Shift+> =Increase Font Size

Ctrl+Alt+> = Standard Size

Ctrl+Shift+> = Increase Font size

Ctrl+Shift+< = Decrease Font Size

Ctrl+Shift+B = Bold

Ctrl+Shift+I = Italic

Ctrl+Shift+U = Underline

Ctrl+Shift+C = Center Align

Ctrl+Shift+J = Justify

Ctrl+Shift+L = Left Align

Ctrl+Shift+R = Right Align

Ctrl+Shift+/ = Strikethrough

Ctrl+Shift+V = Reverse

Ctrl+T = Character Specs

Ctrl+Shift+K = All Caps

Ctrl+\ = Subscript

Ctrl+Shift+\ = Superscript

Ctrl+M = Paragraph

Ctrl+I = Indents/Tabs

Ctrl+3 = Define Style

Ctrl+U = File & Stroke

Alt + Ctrl+F = Frame Option

Ctr+} = Bring To Front

Ctrl+{ = Send To Back

Ctrl+Shift+} = Send Backward

Ctrl+Shift+{ = Bring Forward

Ctrl+Shift+E = Align Object

Ctrl+Alt+E = Text Wrap

Ctrl+G = Group Ctrl+Shift+G = Ungroup

Ctrl+F = Find"